# How to convert 0-1 image float array to 0-255 int array

Tags: python, image, numpy, matplotlib, float32

```py
import matplotlib
import numpy as np

photo=plt.imread('Feynman.png')
plt.figure
plt.subplot(121)
plt.imshow(photo)
photo*=255
plt.subplot(122)
plt.imshow(photo)
```

- Plot results in:

  - `Clipping input data to the valid range for imshow with RGB data ([0..1] for floats or [0..255] for integers).` and only displays an image in the first subplot

[image]

- Used image

[image: the image I use]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The issue is `photo*=255` is still an array of floats.

  - Look at the photo array.
  - Add `photo = photo.astype(int)` after `photo*=255`.
  - `X` in [`.imshow`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html) should be `int` type when the array is 0-255: *(M, N, 3): an image with RGB values (0-1 float or 0-255 int)*

```py
photo = plt.imread('Feynman.png')

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(8, 5))

print(photo[0][0])

ax1.imshow(photo)

photo*=255

print(photo[0][0])

photo = photo.astype(int)

print(photo[0][0])

ax2.imshow(photo)

[output]:
[0.16470589 0.16470589 0.16470589]
[42. 42. 42.]
[42 42 42]
```

[image]